# JSdoc doclet for handlebars helpers

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, jsdoc, handlebarshelper

I have JSdoc set up for a small application i'm building. I started recently adding doclets to my handlebars helpers files as well, but i'm having trouble properly annotating the pattern.

```
/**
 * My helper Name 
 * My helper description
 *
 * @method myHandlebarsHelper
 * @param options.hash.data {object} - some object
 * @param options.hash.param {string} - some string
 * @returns {string} some output string
 **/
```

Also, I want to ensure that the handlebars helpers have their own self contained section in the doc output. Currently everything is output to the Global section. Should I be using @namespace or @external to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's up to you how you would like to structure your project. You could place all helpers in an own section. Or group the different helpers with the other code they are related to.

Comment: I guess the issue I have is I don't know how to create a unique section for a handful of .js files. I'm very new to jsDoc so its possible i'm thinking about this wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@externals` or another alternative would be to document a (fake) module putting i.e.

```
/** @module handlebars */
```

on top of one file and document all helpers to be members of that module. It my not be syntactically correct but it would be nicely separated.

Similarly you could use a namespace

```
/** @namespace HandlebarsHelper */
```

and document all members as

```
/**
 * My helper Name 
 * My helper description
 *
 * @method HandlebarsHelper.myHandlebarsHelper
 * @param options.hash.data {object} - some object
 * @param options.hash.param {string} - some string
 * @returns {string} some output string
 **/
```